# What's the difference between a probability mass function and a discrete probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, terminology, definition

The [Wikipedia page on "probability mass function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) says "The **probability mass function** is often the primary means of defining a **discrete probability distribution**" (emphasis added).  I was under the impression that those two terms were completely synonymous.  What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is subtle. I think it helps to realize that a (probability) distribution is a more general concept. A distribution is something intrinsic to a random variable and determines/describes the behaviour of it. In contrast, a probability mass function (PMF) is one way to concretely describe the distribution quantitatively. Things to note:

- In general, a distribution does not necessarily have a PMF or a probabilty density function (PDF). However, a discrete distribution always has a PMF, and a PMF always describes a discrete distribution, and therefore the two things are basically the same.
- You should think of a PMF as just one way to describe/define a dicrete distribution. We could also use the cummulative density function for example, or any other exotic description we can think of.
- Maybe you can very loosely think like this: The distribution is what carries out the random experiments, and it might look at the PMF to decide what to do, or it might look at something else.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the statement is the probability mass function can define the **distribution** of a discrete random variable, but the distribution is not the same thing as the **distribution function**

The probability mass function for a discrete random variable $X$ is $P(X = k)$. The probability **distribution function** often refers to the cumulative distribution function, $P(X \leq k)$.

I think when speaking or writing, people often drop the 'function' at the end, hopefully it'll be clear from context what they mean.

Answer (score -1):

The probability mass function is a function with whom you can calculate probability of a random variable.

Discrete probabilty distribution is about a way a random variable can behave in terms of the values it can assume.

Comment: If your second sentence is implying that the phrase "Discrete probability distribution" means that a random variable can't assume a continuous range of possible values, isn't that actually the phrase "discrete random variable?"

Comment: Not exactly. A discrete probability distribution says how a discrete random variable follows a pattern of distribution, like Poisson distribution, Binomial distribuition, Geometric etc. Discrete random variable is a variable that follows any specific discrete distribution.

Comment: Then what's the probability mass function?

Comment: It's a function associated with each distribution that gives the probability at each possible value of the random variable. Each probability distribution has it's specific probability mass function. For example, the PMF of a binomial random variable having parameters $(n, p)$ is given by $p(i) = $\left(\matrix{n\\p}\right)$ p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$

Comment: Correction: $p(i) = \left(\matrix{n\\p}\right) p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$

Comment: I don't think your correction is correct - is that supposed to be an $i$ in the bottom of the choose?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: Are you saying that a discrete probability distribution is just a family of related PMFs?  Instead of just using virtually identical words to describe both terms, can you either give a concrete definition of each, or give a concrete example in which you give both?

Comment: Each discrete probabilty distribution has it's own probabilty mass function. It's just this.

Comment: The example is: the binomial probability distribution has the probability mass funcion $p(i)$ as given above.

Comment: If you say that a random variable has binomial distribution, then it's possible values follows the probabilities given by $p(i).$

Comment: I can't tell if you're just trolling me.  Suppose that 34% of my socks are blue, 44% are red, and 22% are green, and I wear each sock equally often.  If we consider my socks to be a random variable $S$, please explicitly give BOTH $S$'s discrete probability distribution AND $S$'s probability mass function.